Unable to copy Refresh Token from ODBC Data Source Administrator
I'm trying to connect to BigQuery from Python and I need to use the refresh token that is generated but it's protected from being copied, is there something missing in order to copy the refresh token? As my friend's ODBC driver looks different where they can actually copy and see the refresh token.

